# I couldnt figure out how can I handle line too long > 79 pep8 rule?

Tags: python, pep8

I didnt clearly understand  pep8 rules. 
How can I split this line to handle "line is too long error" ?
Please can you give me spesific information ?

```
messages.append(" ".join([json.loads(response)[0]["screen_name"], "unfollowed you"]))
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, your line is 85 characters long, which is longer than 79. You can reformat this line as follows to get each line under 79 characters.

```
messages.append(" ".join([json.loads(response)[0]["screen_name"], 
                          "unfollowed you"]))
```

Or, you could split it up:

```
message = " ".join([json.loads(response)[0]["screen_name"], "unfollowed you"])
messages.append(message)
```

Or even more:

```
screen_name = json.loads(response)[0]["screen_name"]
arr = [screen_name, "unfollowed you"]
message = " ".join(arr)
messages.append(message)
```

I would recommend splitting it up like this because this makes the intent of your code more clear. We no longer live in an age where conserving characters matter, so you may as well be a bit more verbose. Of course, you should use names that are semantically meaningful - I just generically named the variable `arr` because I'm not sure what exactly it represents.

Comment: my line is 106 characters, I have spaces before code. And when I try to split code isnt working. this is not nice.

Comment: @AmyObrian Update your question with details, then.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `" ".join()`, you could just do:

```
username = json.loads(response)[0]["screen_name"]
msg = "{} unfollowed you".format(username)
messages.append(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `str.join` here.  Instead, you can use `+`:

```
messages.append(json.loads(response)[0]["screen_name"]+" unfollowed you")
#                                notice the space here--^
```

Making this change trims the line to 73 characters.

---

If you need still more characters trimmed, then you can split the functionality of the line over multiple lines.  Below is an example:

```
mes = json.loads(response)[0]["screen_name"]+" unfollowed you"
messages.append(mes)
```

This change makes the lines 62 characters and 20 characters respectively.